# How to count number of iterations in a for loop C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to count loop iterations and show it to the user using a LABEL. Tried many solutions but no luck. 
Any suggestions regarding this? 
Thanks in advance!
Tried this as well.

```
for (int x = 0; x < DataGridView.Rows.Count; x++)
        {                
            CountLabel.Text = x.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for BackgroundTask. You can then "report progress" within the loop, then update the label in your progress handler.

Comment: Why can't you use the loop counter variable? And then show the label with an appropriate delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop has a built in counter - for example:

```
for(int i=0; i <= maxValue; i++)
{ 
    // do stuff

    yourLabel.Text = i.ToString();
    yourLabel.Update();
}
```

Perhaps you are referring to a a foreach loop (`foreach(var x in y)`).
In that case, you need to add a counter yourself:

```
var loopCounter = 0;
foreach(var x in y)
{
    // do stuff

    yourLabel.Text = loopCounter.ToString();
    yourLabel.Update();
    loopCounter++;
}
```

Comment: But my question is how to show the progress in terms of loop or number of iteration. more simply i want the label to show the number of iterations in such a way that label updates according to iteration process.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: It works but still there is a problem. i.e. i have 4 rows in datagridview and when the for (int x = 0; x < DataGridView.Rows.Count; x++){ Label.Text = x.ToString();
    Label.Update();} Starts and at the end it only shows number up to 3 instead of 4 as there a 4 rows.

Comment: `Label.Text = (x+1).ToString();`...

Answer (score 1):

Declare the index outside the for loop, so you can access it afterwards.

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < smsCount ; i++)
{
    //Send SMS
}
//You can access i here
```

If you are using foreach loop

```
int count = 0;
foreach (SMS sms in SMSlist)
{
    //Send SMS
    count++;
}
```

You access both i and count outside the loop. You can even declare them in a global scope, if you need to access them from other methods or classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loopcounter=0;
foreach(var x in y){
      loopcounter++;
      label.text=loopcounter.toString();     
      //delay();
}
```

You should be writing this in a progress Handler or a separate thread. As the speed of the loop is much faster than the label can display the text. Hence if you directly do this without the delay you might not get the effect you want.

**OR**

You can also use a [Progress Bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx) to display the progress of sending the SMS.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i;

            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 200;

            for (i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = i;
            }

        }
```